# Конвертирование .mxl в pdf или excel (средствами php)

Tags: php, 1с

Нужно преобразовать файл *.mxl (от 1С) в pdf или excel. Возможно ли сделать это средствами php? Работающих библиотек\наработок в этом ключе я не нашел. Различные "онлайн конвекторы" - ни один не смог сделать данное преобразование. В связи с этим вопрос - это в принципе возможно сделать?
Можно ли как-то средствами php прочитать документ .mxl? (не получая набор чисел, текста, символов неизвестной структуры в формате похожем на json)

```
MOXCEL\00\00\00\00{8,1,11,
{"#","",1,1,"#","Язык по умолчанию","Язык по умолчанию",0},
{128,72},
{4,1,
{4,0,
{0},1,2,0,f527dc88-1d39-40b3-bcbb-d98b690ead68,0},0,1,
{4,0,
{0},1,1,0,f527dc88-1d39-40b3-bcbb-d98b690ead68,0},0,1,
{4,0,
{0},0,1,0,f527dc88-1d39-40b3-bcbb-d98b690ead68,0},0,1,
{4,0,
{0},0,1,0,b7438842-27cc-42a3-846f-2250cd9c1bc3,0},0},0,
{0,0},
{0,0},
{0,0},
{0,0},
{0,0},
{0,0},0,2,28,0,0,3,5,
...
```

Демонстрационные файлы можно взять тут https://v8.1c.ru/static/1s-predpriyatie-rabota-s-faylami/

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Зависит от того, что внутри `.mxl` - зная структуру можно написать свой парсер в любой другой формат. Но в сети вроде пишут, что такие файлы должен открывать `Excel`. А после пересохранения в его родной формат - можно уже конвертнуть и в `pdf`

Comment: А откуда идёт файл? Может проще попросить тех, кто его предоставляет сразу в нужный формат сохранять? Что за данные несет он в себе?

Comment: файл от 1С, "акты сверки" . Хоть содержимое разных файлов похоже, но структура в итоге может отличаться (т.е. "в лоб" - относительно номера строк\элемента -  парсить не получится)

Comment: Просто 1С умеет сразу сохранять в xls, pdf и прочие форматы. Может, решение проблемы намного проще. Просто попросить их не в этом формате присылать?

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим комментарием! Из 1С сразу сохраняйте в xls или pdf

Comment: @Sagittarius хорошо когда на другой стороне программист есть. но вот я получаю ХЗ контейнер с данными для печати по soap транспорту. перепаковать это в moxel - 10 минут.. а вот что с этим делать дальше пока затуп. Программировать на 1с обработку с вэб сервисом похоже прийдется.

Comment: @eri, так если нет "с той стороны" программиста, кто вам тогда данные отправляет? Не понимаю контекста вашей проблемы.

Comment: @Sagittarius, типовая конфигурация, ентерпрайс дата

Comment: @eri, все равно не пойму. Типовая по своей воли без настроек отправлять не будет.

Comment: @Sagittarius в моем кейсе всё очень интересно и хитровывернуто. Присоединенный файл с Энтерпрайз дата. У тс наверняка проще.

Comment: @eri, так кто это файл вам присылает?!

Comment: я, сам себе. по соапу.))) но я не программист в 1с чтоб настроить пересылку в пдф.

Answer (score 0):

Средствами PHP или другим языком кроме 1с это не возможно на данный момент.

## Вариант 1

Можно воспользоваться [бесплатной программой 1С:Предприятие — работа с файлами](https://v8.1c.ru/static/1s-predpriyatie-rabota-s-faylami/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохраняет в любой формат.

## Вариант 2

Можно открыть эти файлы [на демке в облаке](https://accounting.demo.1c.ru/accounting/ru_RU/) - кнопка в правом верхним углу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По кнопке печать выдаст PDF

Comment: Скажу больше, не обязательно даже какую-либо конфигурацию устанавливать. Можно просто пустую базу развернуть. Сама платформа 1С поддерживает работу с файлами mxl и пр.

Comment: я и не предлагаю устанавливать даже платформу. дергаем отдельную программу или левое облачко